# Yii: BELONGS_TO relation returns null if I change its name

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I would like to know why the framework might have this strange behavior.

If I define the relation in my Event model as `weird` or any other name besides `interest`, it works properly getting an object of the class `Interest`.

```
public function relations() 
{
    return array_merge(
        parent::relations(),
        array(
            'weird' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Interest', 'interest_id'),
        ));
}
```

But if I change the name to `interest` it returns `null`

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'interest' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Interest', 'interest_id'),
    );
}
```

So simply changing the name to interest means the relation will return `null`

Comment: Do you have any variables on the Event called `interest` you can't override native class variables with Yii specials like relations and magic methods. If not then something stranger is going on here.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. I've added it as an answer so you've got something to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any variables on the Event called interest you can't override native class variables with Yii specials like relations and magic methods. If not then something stranger is going on here.

Comment: Thanks, it made it, I had a variable called interest.